# Proper Rust match idiom

Tags: recursion, switch-statement, rust

I realize the language is at 0.9/0.10 and undergoing breaking changes still (like dropping `do` this week?), but am curious to know if I'm using sound idiomatics here. I've implemented two versions of the change-making algorithm, one naive and one that looks 'better' in my opinion.

This is for 0.9. Both snippets compile and yield identical results in a couple `assert!`'s

```
fn count_change_naive(cents: int, coins: &[int]) -> int {
    if (cents == 0) {
        1
    } else if (cents < 0) {
        0
    } else {
        if coins.iter().len() > 0 {
            let new_amount: int = cents - coins[0];
            let coins_tailed: &[int] = coins.tail();
            count_change_naive(cents, coins_tailed) + count_change_naive(new_amount, coins)
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty unwieldy IMO. I tried to implement the following:

```
fn count_change_idiomatic(cents: int, coins: &[int]) -> int {
    match cents {
        n if cents == 0                     => 1,
        n if cents < 0                      => 0,
        n if coins.iter().len() > 0         => {
            let new_amount: int = cents - coins[0];
            let coins_tailed: &[int] = coins.tail();
            count_change_idiomatic(cents, coins_tailed) + count_change_idiomatic(new_amount, coins)
        },
        _                                   => 0
    }
}
```

I get unused variable warnings on account of the `n` in the match, but I'm uncertain how to avoid this without an ugly if-else pyramid. Can it be done? Am I missing anything significant in the second implementation?

EDIT: have cleaned up some to meet some of the suggestions, but left intact for comparision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a significant simplification of things, improving various idiomatic things:

```
fn count_change_naive(cents: int, coins: &[int]) -> int {
    if cents == 0 {
        1
    } else if cents < 0 {
        0
    } else if coins.len() > 0 {
        let new_amount = cents - coins[0];
        let denom_tailed = coins.tail();
        count_change_naive(cents, denom_tailed) + count_change_naive(new_amount, coins)
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

- avoid `return` when it's not necessary;
- no parentheses around the conditions in `if` statements
- four spaces instead of two (standard Rust community style)
- reduce nesting of `if`/`else` things where possible (`else { if A { B } else { C } }` → `else if A { B } else { C }`)

And another change I'd make with the appropriate information: liberal commenting of the meaning of things. Possibly even shifting the recursive calls into their own statements (this will often enhance readability and has no runtime cost):

```
let ???1 = count_change_naive(cents, demon_tailed);
let ???2 = count_change_naive(new_amount, coins);
???1 + ???2
```

Comment: I realize I hadn't cleaned up the var names completely prior to posting--I definitely appreciated shifting the recursive calls into their own lines.

Comment: Don't use `vec.iter().len()`! That's O(n), but `vec.len()` is O(1).

Comment: @dbaupp: ohh, yes. I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 5):

To no get the warnings for the variable you have no use for, you just don't use it:

```
fn count_change_idiomatic(cents: int, coins: &[int]) -> int {
    match cents {
        _ if cents == 0                     => 1,
        _ if cents < 0                      => 0,
        _ if coins.iter().len() > 0         => {
            let new_amount: int = cents - coins[0];
            let coins_tailed: &[int] = coins.tail();
            count_change_idiomatic(cents, coins_tailed) + count_change_idiomatic(new_amount, coins)
        },
        _                                   => 0
    }
}
```

Comment: But still, using `match` in this way is not idiomatic.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan it seems fine to me (although `_ if cents == 0 => 1` could be `0 => 1`)

Comment: @dbaupp: using match where all clauses are `_ if X` seems to me to be abusing `match`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, meh, it's nicer than an if-else chain; and it's even used [in libstd](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/num/f32.rs#L192-L226) (and [again](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/char.rs#L337-L343)).

Answer (score 5):

You can use pattern matching on vectors to avoid the length-taking, indexing and tailing:

```
fn count_change_idiomatic(cents: int, coins: &[int]) -> int {
    match (cents, coins) {
        (0, _)                        => 1,
        _ if cents < 0                => 0,
        (_, [first, .. coins_tailed]) => {
            let new_amount = cents - first;
            count_change_idiomatic(cents, coins_tailed) + 
                count_change_idiomatic(new_amount, coins)
        }
        _                             => 0
    }
}
```

The `..` part of the pattern matches the rest of the vector (in this case, everything but the first element).